# Lambda - SQS Event: Batch Size, number of container spawning and termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-lambda-containers

Here is my Lambda function:

```
LambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Description: Lambda Function that is spawned via an SQSEvent
    FunctionName: LambdaFunctionName
    Handler: 'com.amazon.krakenscreenruleengineservicelambda.handler.RulesSubscriptionConsumerHandler::handleRequest'
    Runtime: java8
    Events:
      SubscriptionEvent:
        Type: SQS
        Properties:
          Queue:
            Fn::GetAtt: [SubscriptionQueue, Arn]
          BatchSize: 1
    Timeout: 890
    MemorySize: 1024
```

I've set `BatchSize` as `1`.

1 assumption I am making is that, a single Lambda container spawning is determined by it's specific **START** and **END** `requestId`. If there are 5 such **START** and **END** `requestId`, that means 5 unique containers were spawned.

Now does this mean that within a **START** and **END** `requestId`, exactly `1` message is processed and for the next message a new container is spawned with a new START and END `requestId` EVEN if the previous container had the Memory and Time to execute more requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have specified batch size of 1, then the request will include a single SQS message. So "between START and END requestId" would be the log for a single message being processed by Lambda.

However, the same container could be called again with another request, after it has finished. [Containers in AWS Lambda can be reused](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/). They are not used for more than one request at a time, but they can be used for many sequential requests.

The time limit on an AWS Lambda function is the time it takes to process a single request. So if the container is reused the time limit starts over with each request.

A single Lambda container could run for hours/days/months, etc., if it is seeing heavy utilization, or if you have provisioned concurrency. It just has a maximum of 15 minutes (or less depending on the configuration) to process a single request.

---

This is officially documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html), under the "Lambda execution environment lifecycle" section.